# Attempted to read or write protected memory after extern function

Tags: c#, dll

this message is appearing in C# code after calling a function from dll
code is like this

```
function();
int i = 0;
```

on second line it says that there is an unhandled exception of type "System.AccessViolationException"... Attempted to read or write protected memory

Comment: What is `function()` ? how is it defined? if it is an `extern`, does the actual implementation agree with the declaration? In particular, is the return type (`void`, `int`, etc) correct? That message usually means: you've unbalanced the stack, or similar. And a good way to do that: have the `extern` method return a value when you promised not to, or don't return a value when you said you would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If function is external there's something wrong with the declaration.
This happens because your return value or your parameters types aren't of the wrong size, and an error occurs with data "popped" from stack